# Generating Silence with pyDub

Tags: python, audio, mp3, wav, pydub

I've found pyDub, and it seems like just what I need:

http://pydub.com/

The only issue is with generating silence. Can pyDub do this?

Essentially the workflow I want is:

1. Take all the WAV files in a directory
2. Piece them together in filename order with 1 sec of silence in between
3. Generate a single MP3 of the result

Is this possible?  I realize I could create a WAV of silence and do it that way (spacer GIF flashback, anyone?), but I'd prefer to generate the silence programmatically, because I may want to experiment with the duration of silence and/or the bitrate of the MP3.

I greatly appreciate any responses.

Comment: +1 I do have flashbacks of spacer gifs

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The pydub sequences are composed of `pydub.AudioSegment` instances. The [pydub quickstart documentation](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) only shows how to create AudioSegments from files.

However, reading [the source](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/audio_segment.py), or even more easily, running `pydoc pydub.AudioSequence` reveals

```
pydub.AudioSegment = class AudioSegment(__builtin__.object)
 |  AudioSegments are *immutable* objects representing segments of audio
 |  that can be manipulated using python code.
 …
 |  silent(cls, duration=1000) from __builtin__.type
 |      Generate a silent audio segment. 
 |      duration specified in milliseconds (default: 1000ms).
```

which would be called like (following the usage in the quick start guide):

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
second_of_silence = AudioSegment.silent() # use default
second_of_silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=1000) # or be explicit
```

now `second_of_silence` would be an AudioSegement just like `song` in the example

```
song = AudioSegment.from_wav("never_gonna_give_you_up.wav")
```

and could be manipulated, composed, etc. with no blank audio files needed.

Comment: As the author of pydub I can verify that this ought to be the accepted answer :)

Comment: @Jiaaro As someone who has just been made aware of pydub, allow me to complement you on the clarity of the API; it makes me wish I had audio compositing to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, msw (and Jiaaro for confirming the answer)!

Comment: @msw Is it possible to add this silence to an existing audio?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Yes, just use `+` between the silence AudioSegment and other AudioSegment